# Set file association by file type, not mimetype

Tags: gnome, 20.10

I have downloaded app, does not require installing just start from folder,  setup `.desktop` file. All works fine. Now I want to associate the file type in Gnome, so I can double-click on a file and it will be opened in that app.

I manage to set up that too, using `~/.config/mimeapps` file. Also, setup icon for that file type. Works great. Where I have problem is that mime file type for this file is `application/octet-stream` and this associate many other octet-stream files (basically every unknown file type) to be opened with this app.

Is it possible to somehow narrow this, so a specific file extension is affected? Is it possible?

I am on Ubuntu 20.10 Gnome.

Comment: One option would be to assign a MIME type for the extension. Add a record to your `/etc/mime.types` file and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out, had to create my own MimeType.

Just followed this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes